# asp:Button CommandName as Async Trigger for UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to capture the CommandName from button click events.
I have at the top of the form my script manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then I have four buttons and they trigger an update panel

```
            <div class="grid-toolbar">
            <div class="tb-title">"Colorful Report"</div>
            <div class="tb-commands">
                <div class="left">

                    <asp:Button ID="btnSummary" CssClass="TabButton" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CommandName="Summary" runat="server" Text="Summary" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExceptions" CssClass="TabButton" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CommandName="Exceptions" runat="server" Text="Entry Exceptions" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOverdue" CssClass="TabButton" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CommandName="Overdue" runat="server" Text="Overdue Completions" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Button>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnInfo" CssClass="TabButton" UseSubmitBehavior="true" CommandName="Info" runat="server" Text="Info" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dataWrapper" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 600px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSummary" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExceptions" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOverdue" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnInfo" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInfo" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

I then set the event in Page_Init

```
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            raMetaData.Initialize(HttpContext.Current.Request);
            btnSummary.Click += btnTabClick;
            btnExceptions.Click += btnTabClick;
            btnOverdue.Click += btnTabClick;
            btnInfo.Click += btnTabClick;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            messages.Error("An error occurred while initializing page. Please try again.");
            Logger.Write(MessageType.Exception, ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to get the CommandEventArgs that e.CommandName is part of. e.CommandName is not part of normal EventArgs.

```
        private void btnTabClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string cmd = e.CommandName;
        string cmd = "?";

        switch(cmd)
        {
            case "Summary":
                txtInfo.Text = "This will be summary data";
                break;
            case "Exceptions":
                txtInfo.Text = "This will be exception data";
                break;
            case "Overdue":
                txtInfo.Text = "This will be overdue data";
                break;
            case "Info":
                txtInfo.Text = "This will be info data";
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: hmm.. given the issue, it's odd to me that you have knowledge of and the impression there was even a `CommandEventArgs`.  Commands are different events then Click.  Here, you're using click events to signal, OnCommand is a separate event (and isn't implicitly associated to any action, nor did you wire it up to be used with triggering).  So, having said that, you should be able to get the CommandName from the `sender` (casting `sender` to the proper button type).

Comment: Your title and question seem to be two different considerations.. so I can't tell.. is part of your question here in regards to those triggers functioning improperly with Click (are you observing an issue there)? or were you just scoping this question to the `CommandEventArgs` and signaling notion?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I was referencing this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument?view=netframework-4.8). In there is says to use CommandName and evaluate the CommandEventArgs. I did not set OnCommand in the html control bc I set it in the page init. Can I not set in Page_Init? What should I cast it to? I use this same implamentation in an asp:WebImageButton which CommanEventArgs is part of, and it seems like the MSDN article is saying it should act the same.

Comment: Sorry about the title, I'm not sure how to phrase it... One update panel holding various sets of data. Four buttons outside said panel should trigger a postback and eval the argument and in turn determine the data to present. Also in above comment I meant <asp:ImageButton>

Comment: I understand now: <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSummary" EventName= **"Command"**  /> && btnSummary. **Command** += btnTabCommand;

Comment: ah.. I see.. it's a misleading sample article in this respect.  the `OnCommand=<eventhandler>` is what is creating the association to that delegate, but that isn't a button control click event nor click event handler delegate (it's just named that way).  it probably should have been named 'CommandBtn_OnCommand' here.  The click event notion is somewhat still relevant there because it causes the postback, but there is no handling of it in that regard.

Comment: put a breakpoint on this line *private void btnTabClick(object sender, EventArgs e)*  debug the code, press the different buttons and see what the value of "sender" is

Comment: it would not build. I could not figure out what the proper syntax was. Brett helped guide me to the answer, I had subscribed to the wrong event.